# Search Outlook Calendar Event categories for multiple hits - Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to keep track of Outlook calendar events without the need to store information about them on my own systems. I decided to do this by adding the required ids as categories with their type of id before it as shown in the code sample below.

```json
{
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "createdDateTime": "",
    "categories": [
        "ID1::abc123",
        "ID2::def456"
    ]
}
```

I tried using the 'any' lambda operator and this works fine if I want to filter based on one category using the query below:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=categories/any(x:x%20eq%20'ID1::abc123')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=categories/any(x:x%20eq%20%27ID1::abc123%27))

What I need is a query that will check if an event has both ids so in this case only the events where ID1=abc123 and ID2=def456. I figured [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=categories/any(x:x%20eq%20'ID1::abc123')%20AND%20categories/any(x:x%20eq%20'ID2::def456')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=categories/any(x:x%20eq%20%27ID1::abc123%27)%20AND%20categories/any(x:x%20eq%20%27ID2::def456%27)) should do the trick but this keeps returning empty arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since categories are available to the user (and this is going to look really strange in outlook), I would suggest you to use the transactionId on the events to store the external id. This will automatically deny your new event if you try to create a duplicate.

I know this isn’t the answer you were looking for, but using this solution will be much more feature proof.